# open new browser window within dialog ajax call - jquery NOT popup

Tags: jquery

I am stumped.  How do I open a link "go" in this situation using jquery?

Opened a dialog and when click on activate button. The link should open a new browser window / tab the same as clicking on a link "go" with target=_blank.

```
<div id="dialog">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" >go</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({buttons: {
"Activate": function(event) {
    $.get("404.html").error(function(){ 
    $("#dialog a").click(); //doesnt work
    $("#dialog a").trigger("click"); //doesnt work
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com",'_blank'); //opens a popup, not what i need
    window.location.href //is not what i need since its in same window/tab
       });
    }
}});
</script>
```

Comment: .click() only works on div/span elements, so try $("#dialog").click()

Answer (score 1):

You were partially correct. You do use `window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);`. However, you have to fill in more attributes.

```
window.open('link','mywindow','width='+ $(window).width() +',height='+ $(window).height() +',toolbar=yes, 
location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, 
resizable=yes')
```

Here is good documentation on how to use `window.open`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Below is a short list of the attributes you can use:

1. width=300
   Use this to define the width of the new window.
2. height=200
   Use this to define the height of the new window.
3. resizable=yes or no
   Use this to control whether or not you want the user to be able to resize the window.
4. scrollbars=yes or no
   This lets you decide whether or not to have scrollbars on the window.
5. toolbar=yes or no
   Whether or not the new window should have the browser navigation bar at the top (The back, foward, stop buttons..etc.).
6. location=yes or no
   Whether or not you wish to show the location box with the current url (The place to type http:// address).
7. directories=yes or no
   Whether or not the window should show the extra buttons. (what's cool, personal buttons, etc...).
8. status=yes or no
   Whether or not to show the window status bar at the bottom of the window.
9. menubar=yes or no
   Whether or not to show the menus at the top of the window (File, Edit, etc...).
10. copyhistory=yes or no
    Whether or not to copy the old browser window's history list to the new window.

Comment: mozilla link returns a 404

Comment: @Yasser Updated the mozilla link

Answer (score 0):

you can try `window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_newtab');`. Keep in mind this behaviour is mostly controlled by the browser so the results may vary.

Comment: this opens a popup on chrome.  Any idea of why  $("#dialog a").click(); doesn't work? This is really what I need to do take them to a link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" >go</a>

Comment: Are your `$('#dialog a').click()` events perhaps being blocked as popups in chrome?

Comment: it seems like when i use .click () on any regular <a> element, it doesn't work. It only seems to work on the one i defined the event behavior such as in this example.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing in? Would it be possible to jsfiddle.net it?