# How to open popup in new tab or page?

Tags: wicket

I use Wicket in my web application and I create popup using `radio input` as follows:

```
 <input type="radio" wicket:id="foo" />
```

When I click on this radio button, a popup is comming to the page. How to open the popup in new page or tab? `CTRL + mouse` clikc doesn't help. `Right mouse click` on the radio button doesn't show possibility to do that too.

Comment: "a popup is coming to the page". You should give more details to this part of the question.

Comment: I would like when I click on the radio button, that the popup comes in a new page or new tab and not in the same page, where the radio button is.

Comment: Re-phrasing is not a substitute for providing missing details. What is actually a popup, how it's being launched?

Comment: Your question is missing relevant details like what you use for a popup, what you mean by "popup in new page" and all the relevant code sniplets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by popup you mean ModalDialog: So you would have to open new window [[1]](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Opening-Wicket-Page-in-New-Browser-Tab-Window-tp3752465p3753890.html) via JavaScript and open page where you have this modal dialog configured to show during onLoad event.

Comment: I would like when I click on the radio button, that the popup comes in a new page or new tab and not in the same page, where the radio button is.

Comment: Yes, you can write a custom AJAX callback for the radio onClick like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208603/open-new-browser-window-within-dialog-ajax-call-jquery-not-popup

And on the target page just display in onLoad ModalWindow, you can pass variables trough url mapped PageParameters in JavaScript.